How to solve the integral (antiderivative) of $\sqrt{1+x^3}$?
The antiderivative:
$$
\int{\sqrt{1+x^3}dx}
$$
(the real part, with $x>-1$)
is not an elementary function, using Mathematica it gives me some Hypergeometric function.
How to tackle such indefinite integrals?
And in general antiderivatives for square-root (or n-root) of polynomials?
My attempt: I wrote it as $(1+x^3)^{1/2}$ and then tried some series expansion, but I wasn't able to go too far.

it is not simple https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=integrate+%281%2B+x%5E3%29%5E%281%2F2%29

Typically integrals involving expressions of the form $\sqrt{p(x)}$, where $p$ is a polynomial of degree $> 2$, do not admit a closed-form antiderivative in terms of elementary functions.

It doesn't have an elementary closed-form antiderivative.  Not every function has one.  Famous examples also include:
$$\int e^{-x^2} \, dx, \\
\int \frac{\sin x}{x} \, dx, \\
\int \sin x^2 \, dx, \\
\int x^x \, dx.
$$
Interestingly, your binomial series expansion approach, if performed to completion, is precisely equivalent to a hypergeometric function.  That's why Mathematica returns the result that it does.

The output given by Mathematica is
$$x \; {}_2 F_1 (-\tfrac{1}{2}, \tfrac{1}{3}, \tfrac{4}{3}, -x^3) = x \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-\frac{1}{2})_k (\frac{1}{3})_k}{(\frac{4}{3})_k} \frac{(-x^3)^k}{k!},$$
where $$\frac{(a)_k (b)_k}{(c)_k} = \prod_{j=1}^k \frac{(a+j-1)(b+j-1)}{c+j-1}$$ and the empty product for $k = 0$ is equal to $1$.  Hence
$$\frac{(-\frac{1}{2})_k (\frac{1}{3})_k}{(\frac{4}{3})_k k!} = \prod_{j=1}^k \frac{(j - \frac{3}{2})(j - \frac{2}{3})}{j(j + \frac{1}{3})} = \prod_{j=1}^k \frac{(2j-3)(3j-2)}{2j(3j+1)} = \frac{1}{3k+1} \prod_{j=1}^k \frac{2j-3}{2j},$$ where in the last step we have noted that part of the product is telescoping.
Then compare this with the binomial series expansion
$$(1+x^3)^{1/2} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \binom{1/2}{k} (x^3)^k,$$
whose antiderivative is
$$\int (1+x^3)^{1/2} \, dx = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{3k+1} \binom{1/2}{k} x^{3k+1} + C.$$  In particular, I leave it as an exercise to show
$$\binom{1/2}{k} = \prod_{j=1}^k \frac{3-2j}{2j},$$ using the identity
$$\binom{\alpha}{k} = \frac{\alpha(\alpha-1)\cdots(\alpha-k+1)}{k!}.$$

Yeah, I didn't expect an elementary function, but from the expansion (and taking the antiderivatives of each term), I can't make it back to a hypergeometric function. I saw in other questions the use of Gamma function for similar problems, probably all related stuff, but I'm not able to put things together and work out the solution as given by $Mathematica$

@scipio1465 See amended answer, which I think should allow you to complete the argument.
